# Evil DICOM list all elements

Tags: c#, dicom

I would like to list all the tags of a DICOM file in C#.

I would like something like what is shown in the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7283042/1014189

I'm assuming this is an older version as when I paste it into Visual Studio it is not recognised. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you could use [Evil Dicom](http://www.rexcardan.com/evildicom/):

```
public class DicomManager
{
    public List<Tag> ReadAllTags(string dicomFile)
    {
        var dcm = DICOMObject.Read(dicomFile);
        return dcm.AllElements.Select(e => e.Tag).ToList();
    }
}
```

> UPDATE:
>   As per your comment, let's say you need to show the elements in a component on the UI. I'll give you an example of how you could show all the elements in a console app, but the traversing algorithm is the same in any other presentation technology.

Take a look at how is defined IDICOMElement interface in **Evil Dicom**:

```
  public interface IDICOMElement
  {
    Tag Tag { get; set; }

    Type DatType { get; }

    object DData { get; set; }

    ICollection DData_ { get; set; }
  }
```

It means that an element has all the info you would need to work with it.

Iterate the elements and show the tag name - element value.

```
var dcm = DICOMObject.Read(dicomFile);    
dcm.AllElements
       .ForEach(element => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", element.Tag, element.DData));
```

As you can see, if all you want is to show the value - its string representation - the previous snippet should be enough, but in the element you have more info about the real type of the object inside as well as the collection of values - in case of multi-valued elements.

However you need to be careful because some VRs inside a DICOMObject can be very large, so make sure you do the processing using async methods or worker threads in order to keep you UI responsive and don't get a value out unless you specifically need to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I am using Evil Dicom, it worked a charm, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to get the data of the tag also? So that a list would be "tag name" - "data"?