# Double negative IF statements

Tags: if-statement, double, conditional-statements

While reviewing code, I have come across a few `if` staments using `!` followed by an `!=` in the assessment e.g.

```
if (!(fs.ReadByte() != (byte)'D' ||
      fs.ReadByte() != (byte)'I' ||
      fs.ReadByte() != (byte)'C' ||
      fs.ReadByte() != (byte)'M'))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a DCM");
    return;
}
```

Is there any reason to use a double negative over assessing positive e.g.

```
if ((fs.ReadByte() == (byte)'D' ||
     fs.ReadByte() == (byte)'I' ||
     fs.ReadByte() == (byte)'C' ||
     fs.ReadByte() == (byte)'M'))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a DCM");
    return;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: not really... maybe just for obfuscation purpose...

Comment: are you sure there is a `!` there? looks like a bug.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath I think you might be right.

Comment: Nate: is a DCM file (or stream or whatever) supposed to start with `DICM`? Because this will write "Not a DCM" if it *does* start with `DICM`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two *are* different. The first says "None of these are not equal", the second says "any of these are equal".

If you applied the `!` operator across them, you'd have to change the `||` to an `&&`:

```
if ((fs.ReadByte() == (byte)'D' &&
     fs.ReadByte() == (byte)'I' &&
     fs.ReadByte() == (byte)'C' &&
     fs.ReadByte() == (byte)'M'))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a DCM");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Well spotted. Then would there be any other reason if the || was replaced by &&?

Comment: @Nate: What is the code trying to do? We think it might be backwards.

Comment: @David Robinson It's an answered question related to something I'm working on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2384533/925922.

Comment: @Nate: It's a mistake. This code you provide will give the "Not a DCM" output only if the file *does* start with DICM.

Comment: @David Robinson I thought it might have been an error. But I'm sure I've seen a similar 'if' technique used somewhere else so I thought I'd ask if there was a reason for it. Thanks.

Comment: This is called De Morgan's Law - you can move the `!` inside the parts of the expression if you switch `||` with `&&`. (Obviously in this case it then cancels out with the `!=` resulting in `==`.)

Comment: +1 for being amusingly bug-compatible with the first version :)